# Check if an image is broken on a page

Tags: c#, jquery, image, coded-ui-tests

How do I check if the image loaded has loaded properly or broken ?
I don't want to add 'onload' event to the image.

On going onto a page, i need to identify if any of the images on the page are broken.

Thank You!

Comment: better go with a server side implementation

Comment: i agree this is the correct way to go but since i'm testing it, i would like to handle it client side and when that doesn't work,  then i can go for a server side implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the naturalWidth of the `img` element, it's broken if the naturalWidth is 0.

```
var x = document.getElementById("myImg").naturalWidth;
```

Comment: I think this is a good solution where i can loop over all the images on the page and check for any broken images - but i have a doubt - what if when there is a broken image it gets replaced by an 'image did not load' image ? will the 'naturalWidth/naturalHeight' still show 0/undefined ?? or will it show the width of the new 'image did not load' image that replaced the original image ?

Comment: It will show the width of the new 'image did not load' image.

Comment: This works for me absolutely fine as long as there's no 'replace image'. Thank You Jay!

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery error function

```
$('img').error(function(){
        alert("miss " + $(this).attr("src") ); 
});
```

inside the function you can do some action

Comment: Thank you for the reply ! I will see if this is plausible in my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the load() function in Jquery. Example

```
$("#Img").load(function() {
   alert('I loaded!');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: what happens if he has 1000 images on a page with each 5mb in size?

Comment: and you forgoth the url of the images

Comment: Thanks for the reply James ! There would be quite a lot of images i have to check dynamically and quickly to just verify if the page has any broken images. So i would be concerned with the time consumption and the data i'd have to procure to have this solution work.